# Mylyn: How to exclude maven parent

Tags: mylyn

In a multi-module maven project, Mylyn adds newly opened files to the context multiple times: once for the project where the file really lives, and then once again for each parent project in the hierarchy. It is possible to remove the parent references but they reappear.

What makes things worse is that Mylyn shows fully opened path branches for each folder in the parent project that contains files. That clutters the Package explorer a lot.

Is it possible to tell Mylyn to disregard maven parent projects in the workspace?

Comment: It is possible using working sets.  
see http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/User_Guide#Working_Set_Integration  

- Create a working set that contains only non-parent projects, then go to the package explorer and use the small triangle from the package explorer toolbar to open the working set menu.  

- Choose 'Top-level Elements-Working Sets'. That gives you a package explorer with two folders: 'Other projects' and your working set containing the projects that are no parent projects.  

- From the context menu of your working set, choose 'Go Into'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible using working sets.
see http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/User_Guide#Working_Set_Integration

- Create a working set that contains only non-parent projects, then go to the package explorer and use the small triangle from the package explorer toolbar to open the working set menu.
- Choose 'Top-level Elements-Working Sets'. That gives you a package explorer with two folders: 'Other projects' and your working set containing the projects that are no parent projects.
- From the context menu of your working set, choose 'Go Into'